# how to know which checkbox was clicked on?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, checkbox

I have a list of checkboxes. I need to know which was was clicked.
I can't do a loop with

```
if(form1.news[i].checked)
```

Because there can be others that are already checked.
I've tried using

```
this.form.id
this.from.checkboxname.id
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: at which point do you want to know this? when it's clicked on or at submit?

Comment: when it's clicked.
I have a function:
 onclick=\"update(this.form,this.form.news.id,'news.php')\"/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your onclick() function is on the checkbox, `this.id` should work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

The event object will contain a reference to the element that was clicked.

For [example](http://jsfiddle.net/hqD4e/) (using YUI to abstract the browser differences for event binding, other libraries do similar things and you can use raw DOM if you don't mind abandoning old-Internet Explorer):

```
YUI().use('node', 'event', function (Y) {
    Y.one('#container').delegate('click', function (e) {
        alert(e.target.get('value'));
        e.stopPropagation();
    }, 'input[type=checkbox]');
});
​
```

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATED** [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/kvUqt/6/):

```
 $(function() {
            $('#myButton').click(function() {
                $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function(i) {
                    alert(this.value);
                });
            });
        });​
```

Comment: Please put the code here, or your answer will be useless on its own.

Comment: That will give all the checked checkboxes, not the one which was clicked.

Comment: @Quentin-it will check for all the checkboxes and return the checked ones.

Comment: @DotNetter — Exactly. That is not "the one which was clicked". It might not even include the one that was clicked if it was being unchecked. The question explicitly states that it doesn't want to get all the existing checked inputs.

Comment: @Quentin-Is that what the OP needed?